# Why don't we need to input parameters in a selector :: Swift 4

Tags: swift, selector

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(addNewTask(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.init("com.todolistapp.addtask"), object: nil)

@objc func addNewTask(_ notification: NSNotification) {

}
```

Why don't we need to explicitly input the value of the addNewTask parameter.

Comment: You don’t specify it when you add the observer because the notification object won’t be created until the notification is triggered at some future point in time. The selector is just saying “a method with such and such ‘signature’” and the parameter value is not part of the method signature but rather supplied when the method is called later.

Comment: Don't use NS... classes in Swift if there is a native counterpart for example `Notification`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(addNewTask(_:)), name: 
NSNotification.Name.init("com.todolistapp.addtask"), object: nil)  //1

@objc func addNewTask(_ notification: NSNotification) {  //2

}
```

At line 1, You are just telling the NotificationCenter that you want to listen to the notification of a particular kind and when that notification will be fired you want to get called one function. You are telling about the method using the `selector`. You make the selector using function name.

Your specified method will not be called when you are at line 1. It will be called by the `NotificationCenter` when notification will be fired actually. And at that time you will actually have the notification object that should be passed to the function.

It depends on you whether you want that parameter or not. You can omit it also if you want.